# How can I prove that if a matrix $A$ is symmetric so is its transponse $A^T$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

How can I prove that if a matrix $A$ is symmetric so is its transponse $A^T$.

I know that this claim is true because $A = A^T$ but how can I prove it formally?

And are there two symmetric matrices such that their marix product is not symmetric.

Thanks

Comment: @ Alcakram, is your first question a joke ? If the answer is NO, then study sewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ is 
$$
a_{ij} = a_{ji} \quad (i, j \in \{ 1, \dotsc, n \}) \quad (*)
$$

The definition of the transpose $A^T = (b_{ij})$ of a $m \times n$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ is
$$
b_{ij} = a_{ji} \quad (i \in \{ 1, \dotsc, n \}, j \in \{ 1, \dotsc, m \}) \quad (**)
$$

For a symmetric matrix $A$, we have $m = n$, and for the elements of $A^T$ we have
$$
\underbrace{
b_{ij} 
\stackrel{(**)}{=} a_{ji} 
\stackrel{(*)}{=} a_{ij} 
\stackrel{(**)}{=} b_{ji}
}_{(*)}
$$
so $A^T$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
(A^T)^T=A^T.
$$

(I substituted $A^T=A$.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint (almost answer):

By the **very, very** definition of "transpose of matrix", convince yourself that transposing twice gets us back to the original: $\;(A^t)^t=A\;$

Example for the second part:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\!-1\end{pmatrix}=\ldots$$

Comment: but I know that a matrix is symmetric if and only if it is a square $nxn$ matrix, so if I transponse that matrix I am going to have the my original matrix

Comment: What you say "you know" would mean **all square matrices** are symmetric, which of course is absurd...

Comment: Sorry I meant that a matrix can be symmetric if it is square

Comment: @Alcakram Well...yes, of course. Again, what is **your** definition of "symmetric (square) matrix"?

Answer (score 0):

if a matrix $A$ is symmetric then $aij = aji$;
if $B = A^T$ then $bij = aji$

since $bij = aji = aij$ then $B = A^T = A$